# iPhone presenting and dismissing navigation view controller in storyboards?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have root view that presents navigation controller with content controller, this is how it looks like:
[image]

NavigationController is presented modally, and ProjectTypeSelectionView is his root controller. When tapping logout button i want to dismiss modal view and return to LoginScreenViewController.

So i set in prepareSegue LoginScreen as delegate:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

 UINavigationController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;

 if ([[destination ] respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)]) {
     NSLog(@"%@", destination);
     [destination setValue:self forKey:@"delegate"];
}
}
```

and then inside ProjectTypeViewController add this method:

```
 - (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
      [self.delegate projectTypeSelectionViewControllerDidFinish];
 }
```

which is called when logout button is tapped. To my suprise this doesn't dismiss controller. Nothing happens, even thou everything is connected.

I have traced error to this - when prepareSegue is called NavigationController's delagate is set to LoginScreenViewController, insetad of setting ProjectTypeController's delegate to LoginScreenViewController.

How do i solve this properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

 UINavigationController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
UIViewController *vc = [[destination viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
vc.delegate = self;
}
```

To make this code more robust you might want to check if the desitinationViewController is a UINavigationController